# Is var in Clojure is stored as an object?

Tags: clojure

Is `var` in Clojure is stored as an object?

**Question 1:**
If yes, then object of which class?

**Question 2:**
In Java, we have references stored on the thread stack and the they refer to the objects stored on process heap.
How to interpret `var`s in Clojure like the analogy of objects in Java.

**EDITS:**

To try the first question by myself, I used `type`/`class` to check the class of the object.

`Case 1:`

```
(def a 100)
(type a)
```

O/P:
java.lang.Long

In this case, it is clear that `a` is an object of **Long** class.

But, how to check the same thing for functions. For example -

`case 2:`

```
(type identity)
```

O/P:

```
clojure.core$identity
```

So, from the `case 2`, `type` returns the namespace instead of class.

How to get the class?

Answer (score 2):

If you call `(type x)` on some previously defined `x`, then you are using the *value* of `x`.  If you want to find out about the type of the var, you need to look at the var:

```
user=> (type #'a)
clojure.lang.Var
```

A naive way to get information about object is the `bean` function

```
user=> (bean #'a)
{:watches {}, :validator nil, :public true, :threadBinding nil, :bound true, :dynamic false, :macro false, :class clojure.lang.Var, :rawRoot 42, :tag nil}
```

Finding out about the hierarchy via `parents`:

```
user=> (parents (class #'a))
#{java.io.Serializable clojure.lang.IFn clojure.lang.Settable clojure.lang.IRef clojure.lang.ARef}
```

Everything in the JVM is an `Object`-descendant (except the primitive types).

Comment: What is the order of parent hierarchy @cfrick?

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L20) states `public final class Var extends ARef implements IFn, IRef, Settable, Serializable`.  The result from `parets` is a set, so it has no order. And since clojure existed long before `default` methods where a thing in java and i'd assume that it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** - typed original answer too quickly

---

The concept of a "Var" is built into the Clojure language/compiler. A `Var` is normally accessed via a namespaced symbol. Each namespace is implemented like a map, where the map keys are Clojure symbols and the map values are Clojure `Var` objects.

Each `Var` object is a mutable object that points to an immutable Clojure "value" (eg `5`, `[1 2 3]`, `{:a 1 :b 2}` etc).

Please see this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), esp "Getting Clojure". For the nitty gritty details, look into the Clojure `namespace` and its [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1597).

- [Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/namespace)

Comment: Note a Clojure Var is implemented as Java class [`clojure.lang.Var`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java) if you wanted to look at low level detail.

Comment: The keys in a namespace are symbols, and the values are vars. You can see this if you write `(ns-map *ns*)`, for example. The var is a real object that knows its name and points (mutably!) to an immutable value.